# Excel VBA hide names defined in Name Manager

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use Excel VBA to hide the "Name1" in name manager. Could you advise the code to hide Name1 with Scope Workbook? Thanks!

```
'Can hide Name1 with scope Sheet1
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Names("Name1").Visible = False
'Can hide Name1 with scope Sheet2
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Names("Name1").Visible = False
'Can hide Name1 with scope Sheet3
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Names("Name1").Visible = False

'TODO: I want to hide Name1 with scope Workbook, but failed.
'The code hidden Name1 with scope Sheet1 instead.
ThisWorkbook.Names("Name1").Visible = False
```

[image: The names to be hidden by Excel VBA]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below (explanations inside the code comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideNames()

Dim xName As Name
Dim NametoHide As String

NametoHide = "Name1" ' <-- modify to whatever name you want to hide

' loop through all names
For Each xName In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If xName.Name = NametoHide Then
        xName.Visible = False
    End If
Next xName

End Sub
```

Comment: sounds good! but what if I JUST want to hide Name1 with scope Workbook, not all scopes? Thanks!

Comment: @TonyChan  did you read the code? Tried to understand it ? Tested it?

Comment: Now I understand! It only loop through the names in the scope workbook but not in the scope worksheets.

Comment: @TonyChan and... it will only hid "Name1" , you can adjust this code for future scenarios quite easily, by modifying the `If..` line